# Asp.net 5 Web.Api + IIS + index.html + Angular 4

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm started working on a new SPA project and decided to use Angular 4. Also, I have an existing backend written in **Asp.Net 5** and use **Web.Api** to fetch data. (no MVC controllers, cshtml etc, backend is only for getting data!)

I created new Angular project near *.csproj and Web.config files are placed (so this is the root of my website).

The problem is - Angular compiles all files to "dist" folder, including index.html however IIS can't find it because it's root folder is one level higher.

**What I have tried:**

1. set `<base href="/dist/">` , but then Angular router navigates to
   `/dist/*route_path*` instead of `*route_path*`
2. set IIS defaultDocument to "/dist/index.html" , but then all bundles a not
   found (404), because it tries to find them near index.html
3. eject Angular webpack config and edit it to reach my goal. I changed
   "Index.html" to "../Index.html" and I have working html with
   bundles, bit urls in *.css files are invalid.. I can't make all them prefixed
   with "/dist/"

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If someone interested, I ended up with IIS URL Rewrite Module as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="site">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api" negate="true" />
            <add matchType="IsFile" pattern="^/images/" negate="true" />
            <!-- the rest of your rules here... -->
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have both the project in one single root domain. Usually its important for SEO.
angular-cli app and webapi both will be on the same root folder and the url rewrite will be something like this

```
<rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
</rule>
```